# Android emulator not showing full display

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

My emulator shows the app in half screen, can anyone help me to fix this issue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIhCA.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options to try:

1. Use `Software` graphics in the AVD emulator options for your device, rather than `Hardware`.
2. If that doesn't work, try to reduce the scaling of your PC, for example reducing it from 200% down to 100% within the Display Settings of Windows.