# Emulator Android Studio in VsCode

Tags: flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm currently using `VS Code` in a project. I have an emulator and I can run devices configured from `Android Studio`. But the problem is that the display I'm getting is not very nice and I would like the device screen to take all the space it should.
**Here's a screenshot of what I get:** [image: Emulator Screenshot]

I tried to change the display settings but nothing. Could someone help me.

Comment: This seems to be a very common issue:
After a quick google:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68067454/android-emulator-not-showing-full-display
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43539759/android-emulator-screen-size-issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45435272/android-emulator-screen-fills-up-only-some-fraction-part-of-actual-android-emula